# How to Use SQlite Random()

Tags: xcode, ios, sqlite, random

I'm aware that to select a random row in SQlite I need the command

> SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY RANDOM() LIMIT X

but how do I use this within xcode to set and display the given value?

I'm practicing this on the Apple sample code `iPhoneCoreDataRecipes` to get a better feel of the `Random()` command.  For this instance, I want to find a random recipe and then display it to the user with a `nameLabel.text`.

Any thoughts on how to set this up?

Answer (score 0):

i don't know this is correct or not but you can try

```
int randomNumber = arc4random() % Limit;
"SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY randomNumber  LIMIT X"
```

Comment: Thanks.  Then would I display this using: nameLabel.text = randomNumber ?

Comment: i guess you want to show the result which was returned by your query... and not the random Number...

Comment: Yeah I'm not wanting a random number but a random row in sqlite.  So I'm trying to figure out how to match this number with the sqlite row.

Comment: that particular randomNumber is your the row which is randomly selected... suppose int randomNumber = arc4random() % Limit;
returns you 4 then 4th row it is